# Perl to delete specific lines

Tags: perl

I have file which has more than 1000 lines, some lines have

```
key="chicago_newyork_plane_1_3_8_7_9_80Bs111010110101101011010110101101011010111001100111010111001100111100110011100111\.com_der_compare,chicago_newyork_plane_1_3_8_7_9_80Bs111010110101101011010110101101011010111001100111010111001100111100110011100111
key="delhi_pune_plane_1_3_8_7_15_16_10_11_9_80Bs100010110101101011010110101101011010111001100111010111001100111100110011100111\.com_der_compare,delhi_pune_plane_1_3_8_7_15_16_10_11_9_80Bs100010110101101011010110101101011010111001100111010111001100111100110011100111
```

I need to add .*

```
key="chicago_newyork_plane.*80Bs111010110101101011010110101101011010111001100111010111001100111100110011100111\.com_der_compare,chicago_newyork_plane.*80Bs111010110101101011010110101101011010111001100111010111001100111100110011100111
key="delhi_pune_plane.*Bs100010110101101011010110101101011010111001100111010111001100111100110011100111\.com_der_compare,delhi_pune_plane.*Bs100010110101101011010110101101011010111001100111010111001100111100110011100111
```

I have written code as,

```
$_ =~s/key="[a-z]+_[a-z]+_[a-z]+_[0-90]+_[0-9]+Bs/key=" [a-z]+_[a-z]+_[a-z]+.*/g;
```

I am unable to override that.
I was able to do if i hard code the values or number of underscore (_) , but don't want to do so

Comment: Why `[0-90]`? Isn't it the same as `[0-9]`? And why one line changed to `.*80Bs` and the other to `.*Bs`? What's the rule there?

Comment: Two examples are inconsistent: the first one keeps the last number (80), the second one doesn't.  Assuming that you don't want that number: `s/key="[a-zA-Z_]\K[0-9_]/.*/`.  Can't test now ...

Comment: (need quantifiers above, `s/key="[a-z_]+\K[0-9_]+/.*/i`, with `/i` for upper/lower case)

Answer (score 1):

```
while (<$fd>) {
    s/\w\K_(?:\d+_)+/.*/;
    say;
}
```

or

```
while (<$fd>) {
    s/(?<=\w)_(?:\d+_)+/.*/;
    say;
}
```

Does the trick for me, I supposed the first result you said you want as the correct one.

Comment: `\K` was introduced in 5.10. You gotta be careful when using `/g` because it's not a lookbehind. But otherwise, it's better because it's easier to read, and because it's more efficient than `(?<=...)` since it just sets the start of match position rather than performing a submatch.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your input data correctly

- word character (`\w` -> KEEP)
- followed by one-or-more underscore + number (`(?:_\d+)+` -> REPLACE)

then this should be the correct solution.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/(?<=\w)(?:_\d+)+/.*/g;
    print;
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
key="chicago_newyork_plane_1_3_8_7_9_80Bs111010110101101011010110101101011010111001100111010111001100111100110011100111\.com_der_compare,chicago_newyork_plane_1_3_8_7_9_80Bs111010110101101011010110101101011010111001100111010111001100111100110011100111
key="delhi_pune_plane_1_3_8_7_15_16_10_11_9_80Bs100010110101101011010110101101011010111001100111010111001100111100110011100111\.com_der_compare,delhi_pune_plane_1_3_8_7_15_16_10_11_9_80Bs100010110101101011010110101101011010111001100111010111001100111100110011100111
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl 
key="chicago_newyork_plane.*Bs111010110101101011010110101101011010111001100111010111001100111100110011100111\.com_der_compare,chicago_newyork_plane.*Bs111010110101101011010110101101011010111001100111010111001100111100110011100111
key="delhi_pune_plane.*Bs100010110101101011010110101101011010111001100111010111001100111100110011100111\.com_der_compare,delhi_pune_plane.*Bs100010110101101011010110101101011010111001100111010111001100111100110011100111
```

I just noticed that your expected output is inconsistent. If you want instead

- word character (`\w` -> KEEP)
- followed by one-or-more underscore + number (`(?:_\d+)+` -> REPLACE)
- followed by underscore (`_` -> REPLACE)
- followed by the string `80B` (-> KEEP)

then it should be:

```perl
s/(?<=\w)(?:_\d+)+_(?=80B)/.*/g;
```

Comment: `\w\K` would be faster than `(?<=\w)`